# "src://domain.com" cannot work.. using firefox 28 and chrome 34

Tags: javascript, url, uri, src

I can't seem to use "src://domain.com" to load any cdn.. this is the code that i put copied from google CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this is the error thrown by chrome:

```
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
```

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

The code works fine if i prepend http: or https// to the URL, is there any reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of URL uses the same protocol than the one used from the initial document.

This means it can only be used for a network protocol if you want to access a remote resource. Don't use it when you open your file in `file:` protocol like in `file://c:\myFile.html`.

The point of this scheme is to let you use either HTTP or HTTPS without having to hardcode your `src` attribute (and without having to serve two different files) [without raising a protocol change warning in the browser](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

More generally, as most AJAX or remote resource use in JavaScript is prevented due to Same Origin Policy, you should never code anything without a HTTP server.

Read more : [Protocol Relative URLs, Why to Use Them, and Common Pitfalls](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/)

Comment: Thank you so much @dystroy for the solution and extra links to learn

Answer (score 0):

You are using a scheme relative URI. This means it will use the same scheme as your HTML document.

HTTP and HTTPS versions of the URI exist. A FILE version does not.

Either do your testing on an HTTP server or use an absolute URI (e.g. one which starts `http://`).

I'd recommend using an HTTP server. There are lots of differences between webpages on HTTP and webpages on a local file system, so development work benefits from having an HTTP environment.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for the explanation, i thought it would only fetch either http:// or https://

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead (note the https:// rather than //)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, run your file on a web server, rather than from your file system

Comment: Thanks @jonathan, I didn't know there was a difference running it from web server and file system until the other mentioned the term "protocol relative URLs/relative URI"